# After the New York 2019 Reproductive Health Act, are there ANY penalties to late-term abortion?

Tags: new-york-state, abortion

The New York 2019 Reproductive Health Act lists conditions under which an abortion *may* be performed (before 24 weeks, woman’s life or health at risk, fetus not viable). And the Act completely removes abortion from the penal code, that is, completely decriminalizes abortion.

What penalty is there, then, for performing an abortion that does *not* meet the conditions, that is, for performing an abortion after 24 weeks on a viable fetus when there is no risk to woman’s life or health?

Where is that penalty specified? If no crime is committed, how would any penalty be imposed?